# Were there multiple versions of the Ricoh 500G?

Tags: repair, rangefinder, ricoh

Some years ago, the shutter release button on my wonderful Ricoh 500G suddenly began to jam at the bottom of its travel.

I took apart the camera and minutely examined the mechanism; the shaft of the button becomes jammed in the collar. I could find absolutely no reason why this should have started occurring.

The camera has remained dismantled since waiting for me to come across a suitable donor camera for parts to repair it.

Well, I found one, and finally found some time to extract the pieces I need - and I discover that while externally these cameras are identical, various internal parts, *including the ones I wanted to swap* have a different design!

I haven't got very deep into the new camera, so I don't know yet how different the cameras are internally.

Were there different versions or generations of this model?

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon for there to be multiple revisions of camera models (or any other type of mass produced product). If you are not mistaken about the identity of the cameras you have disassembled, the internal differences clearly indicate that different versions do exist.